# How to connect with redis server from Mobile app to perform different operation on redis database from Mobile app

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using Redis as a service of AWS for memory cache for a Chat app in Mobile devices. The issue that I am currently facing is I am unable to connect with the Redis server from any Redis client. So far I have read from the Redis documentation that you can't connect outside of the AWS environment.

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/accessing-elasticache.html) it is not recommended to access your Elasticache cluster like you are trying to connect.

> Elasticache is a service designed to be used internally to your VPC. External access is discouraged due to the latency of Internet traffic and security concerns. However, if external access to Elasticache is required for test or development purposes, it can be done through a VPN.

What you may do is creating a new api which communicates with AWS Elasticache Redis cluster and your mobile back-end will communicate with Redis by using this API.

- You may deploy your new api to a EC2 instance, arrange VPC and security groups.
- You may deploy your new api to a lambda, put into the VPC. Your mobile back-end may communicate with Redis via using this lambda(integrated with Api gateway).

By this way it will be more secure, easily manageable(no need to put credentials on your mobile app's), easily maintainable (you may make changes easier).

Comment: How to perform pubsub on the mobile device with Redis?

Comment: @AsadullahMumtaz that would be a completely different question but it is too broad. I am not sure whether you can do it AWS Lambda(you can check SNS as an alternative) but with EC2 communication with redis - you can publish messages from your administrator side to ec2 then it publishes to redis, then your mobile app clients connect to ec2 endpoint to subscribe/read messages.

Comment: many thanks for the detailed answer and comments now I am clear with my understanding. Also, thanks for the suggestion will definitely look SNS as an alternative.